# Trying to use vue resource - plugin.apply is not a function(…)

Tags: vue-resource, vue.js

This is my code. It seems ok?

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import  Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'; 
import $ from 'Jquery';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use('VueResource');

export default {
template: '<canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>',

mounted() {

 this.$http.get('/data/get/pageinsights').then((response) => {
    // success callback
  }, (response) => {

  })
```

Comment: I have the same problem, try with ```Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));```